# Is it safe to combine .aspx and .cshtml pages in a same project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, dynamic, html-table

I am working on a MVC project. All of my pages so far have been .cshtml, but I'm working on a new one that requires dynamic tables that don't lose the rows generated client-side after postback.

I started simulating this with HTML tables storing the value of the first cell of each row in Sessions and filling the rest of the row with the help of SQL queries and Javascript. Problem is, I read somewhere that it ain't convenient to use too much Sessions in projects that are going to be used by a lot of people. On the other hand, I don't trust this simulation of dynamic table since it has a lot of details that can go wrong.

My questions are:
1. Is there a way to do an actual dynamic table on cshtml?
2. Is it safe to put an .aspx pages in a Razor project?

Comment: Yes, safe and "desirable" are not the same thing.  Safe yes. Desirable? Up to you, it's your project.  Please define "dynamic table" In your context.  Do you have and example>

Comment: There's a search table (table 1) that displays the results of a search of employees, with a button on each row that passes that employee info to the other table (table 2).
If you make a new search, table 1 is going to display that new search, but that search is made server-side, and after the postback table 2 info gets lost. "Dynamic" for me would be a table that doesnt lose that info such as an asp:Table

Comment: Safe yes, but it is just bad pattern. If you have problem with views just switch to some frontend tech  knockout for example

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to combine ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor and ASPX View Engines in One Project. Here is how to make it possible http://geekswithblogs.net/wildturtle/archive/2010/10/13/combining-asp.net-razor-and-aspx-view-engines-in-one-project.aspx

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks fam. I'll check it out